# Python Global Variable: sharing between function class then function

Tags: python, class, function, global-variables

I'm trying to get the following global variable storage_i to be accessible to the lvl1 function, I have been able to pass it to other functions inside of the class birdofprey but I can't get it outside of that framework. I have looked around at using global variables between functions, etc, and I have also seen global var usage discouraged. But, basically I am trying to have the value of storage_i summed up from all the threads. So if that could be done without a global variable that would also be great. Any help would be appreciated.

The Code: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
global storage_i
storage_i = i
```

With this:

```
birdofprey.storage_i = i
```

You also have a typo at line 75:

```
storage_ii = stroage_i + storage_ii
```

(`stroage_i` was intended to be `storage_i`)

This line should actually be:

```
storage_ii =  birdofprey.storage_i + storage_ii
```

**EDIT**: Also, without having looked closely at it, your use of a class attribute (storage_i) looks like it's susceptible to race conditions. Consider using mutexes to guard accesses to that attribute. I think you also need to wait for the threads to finish executing before you can access the values.

But I'm not sure if a global (or class attribute) is really what you want. I think what you really want is a thread-local variable that you can access after the thread has finished (see the `Thread.join` method.) If I'm reading that correctly, then forget what I wrote above about mutexes. Instead, set the storage_i attribute as `self.storage_i` (creating a separate instance for each thread.) Then in the `for` loop where you're summing the values, access the value as `urlv.storage_i`. Again, it looks like it's important that you perform a `join` on each thread before you try to access its values.

That's all the help I can offer for now; perhaps tomorrow morning (my time) I can check in again.

Comment: Thanks, I set that up however I think urlv.storage_i doesn't work, currently I tried urlv.self, etc, still looking into what else might fix it since it claims that AttributeError: 'birdofprey' object has no attribute 'storage_i' Code: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py (you can ignore that it says urlvself atm I was just testing different things)

Comment: The issue seems to be that I can access variables that are under the function run, but I can access those under the class birdofprey.

Comment: Okay so I was able to get it to work, I needed to use locking on the threads it seems, though I'll try it later without locking, but for now it works this way. Thanks. Code: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py

Comment: Or rather, the locking make it work, but that means that there aren't multiple threads running anymore since the second thread is waiting on the first.

Comment: So basically fixed the issue with summing the numbers, now new problem about only two threads are running. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360636/python-threading-only-two-active-threads-how-do-i-get-more

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `storage_i` under `lvl1()` then use:

`birdofprey.storage_i`

Well `storage_i` is not a global variable, its a class attribute.

Comment: Okay thanks, but then how do I get access to it when it's set to i under def run(self): ?

Comment: don't use `global storage_i`, you have to access it using `self.storage_i`

Comment: Okay, when I set it to just store as @storage_i = i@ in the function and access it under @lvl1()@ with @storage_ii = birdofprey.self.storage_i + storage_ii@ it claims that - type object 'birdofprey' has no attribute 'self' Code: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py

Comment: You removed the definition of storage_i that you'd had in the lvl1() function. (I think it was simply: `storage_i = 0`) Without that, then indeed there is no storage_i attribute. Also, you don't need `self`. Just `birdofprey.storage_i` works.

Comment: Okay, I made those corrections, however it just prints 0's. Code: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py