# Python Threading: Only two active threads, how do I get more?

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have the following program:

https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py

However, when it's run I only get two active threads are running, how can I make it so that there are more threads running. I have tried doing stuff like `urlv2 = birdofprey(ip2)` where `ip2 = str(host+1)` however that just ends up sending the same thing to two threads. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active count=2 means that you have one of your designed thread (`birdofprey`), and the main thread. This is because you use lock, so the second `birdofprey` thread waits for the first and so on. I didn't get deeper into the algorithm, but it seems that you don't need to lock `birdofprey` threads, since they don't share any data (I could get wrong). If they share, you should make exclusive access to the shared data, and not to lock the whole body of `run`.

**Update upon comment**

1. remove locks (if there is no shared data. `storage_i` is not a shared data.);
2. in the `for` loop` create threads, start them, append to a list;
3. make the second loop over the list of threads, call `join` collect the information you need.

Comment: Yes, they do share, so I did a lock around `self.storage_i` the only problem is then in the `for loop` I run into this problem if I don't join - `AttributeError: 'birdofprey' object has no attribute 'storage_i'`

Comment: Thanks, once I had fixed the error when I tried to implement what THC4k said the first time in regards to the `urlv.join()` and did what you said I was able to get it working correctly. Code: https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/Experimental/demo_async_falcon.py Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

line 75, `urlv.join()` blocks until the thread finishes. So you actually create one thread, wait until it's done and then start the next. The other thread is the main thread.

Comment: Okay so I had there in order be able to sum up the values of `storage_i` now if I can't do that with `urlv.join()` that's fine. Which seems to be the case, but then the issue is - ah nevermind I have made a mistake, the issue was going to be that it reads only `ip` as 9, however this is because I'm not using `self.ip` which is what I should have been using. Okay, so then there is no way to get multiple threads if I keep `urlv.join()`? Since removing it prevents the main thread from finding the variable `storage_i`. Thanks.

Comment: You just have to *start all the threads* before you join them. To do this you have to put each started thread in a list and then join each of them. You should read a introduction to threading too, it's not a topic where you can just guess your way through - see khachik's answer.

Comment: Thanks, yea I was reading through this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm as my guide, the reason it didn't help earlier was because when I tried appending to `source=[]` I was incorrectly using `ip` instead of `self.ip` so even though the program was set up correctly the same url was being accessed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to pull urlv.join() out of the for loop. Right now, because of the join, you're waiting for your new thread to complete before starting the next one.

But for general readability, maintainability, etc., you might want to consider using Python's Queue class to set up a work queue and have a pool of worker threads pulling from it.